# RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nltk, python-3.6

I'm using docker to run an NLP system that uses nltk, languagetool etc...
When I use `docker-compose build --build-arg env=dev` I get the warning message:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning:
>   'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk',
>   but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in
>   unpredictable behaviour warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))

Then when I use `docker-compose up` I get these errors when trying to run my system:

[image]

Please help me figure out how to fix this!

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393764/python-3-6-project-structure-leads-to-runtimewarning)

Comment: Issue is reported in [nltk-github](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2162)

Answer (score 11):

In your Dockerfile:

```
RUN python -c "import nltk;nltk.download('your_library')"
```

After `pip install nltk`