# ipdb: RuntimeWarning: 'ipdb.__main__' found in sys.modules after import of package 'ipdb'

Tags: python, ipdb

I am using ipdb to debug my python like below:

```
python -m ipdb my_test.py -d my_input_config -o my_output
```

and got the following errors:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning: 'ipdb.__main__' found in sys.modules after import of package 'ipdb', but prior to execution of 'ipdb.__main__'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
```

What does this mean and how do I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393764/python-3-6-project-structure-leads-to-runtimewarning)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60922965/3990998 This might be useful

Comment: Typing `__spec__ = None` as soon as `ipdb` starts up seems to solve the "unpredictable" behavior (like the link above says) but it'd be nice to know why this happens and how to solve it without that workaround.