# Why does my function turn into a module when adding imports?

Tags: function, module, python-3.6, python-import

I have a project with the following structure:

```
Root/
|-- project/
|   |-- test/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- test_main.py
|   |   
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |
|   |-- scripts/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- some_script.py
|   |
|   |-- settings/   
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- load_settings.py
|   |   |-- MAPS.py
|   |   |-- TRSFM.py
|
|-- setup.py
|-- README
```

inside my settings folder, I have a couple of py files that contain dicts I store data in -> load_settings.py is used to retrieve these.

My problem is that when I try to import more than one of these in load_settings.py, load_settings.py turns from being a function to a module, which doesn't seem to have any functions when inspected

**__init__.py** (in settings folder)

```py
from .load_settings import load_settings
```

When load settings.py is defined as follows:

**load_settings.py**

```py
from .settings import MAPS

def load_settings(setting):
    return MAPS[setting]
```

and some_script.py with the following code:

**some_script.py**

```py
from project.settings import load_settings

help(load_settings)
```

and the following command is run:

*python -m project.scripts.some_script*

I get the following output:

```
Help on function load_settings in module project.settings.load_settings:

load_settings(setting)
```

but, if I change load_settings.py to include additional imports:

**load_settings.py**

```py
from .settings import MAPS
from .settings import TRSFM

def load_settings(setting):
    return MAPS[setting]

def load_transforms(trsfm):
    return TRSFM[trsfm]
```

and run the same command as above, I get the following output:

```
Help on module project.settings.load_settings in nec.settings:
NAME
    project.settings.load_settings

DATA
    MAPS = {'A': {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd ...

FILE
    /home/user/ws/Root/project/settings/load_settings.py
```

first I thought the issue was with the function and the file (load_settings) having the same name, but changing these made no difference.
I cant figure out why this would happen, as I want to be able to import and call the functions in some_script.py, e.g.:

```
from project.settings import load_settings
a_dict = load_settings('A')
```

which works before adding the second import to load settings, but when the second import is present, it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

which is clear, as the object Im trying to call is no longer a function, and trying to access any functions inside the module, e.g.

```
from project.settings import load_settings as ls
a_dict = ls.load_settings('A')
```

returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'project.settings.load_settings' has no attribute 'load_settings'
```

which again is made clear by the help function -as no functions can be seen inside the module.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add if you're using Python 2 or Python 3? It will be relevant for the answer you get. :-)

Comment: There are things you are not including in your question. First, please make sure you wrote the correct commands and outputs. For example, `help(load_settings)` cannot output help on the function since that is the module you imported. And what causes the error: `'module' object is not callable`?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 The commands and outputs are correct, nothing has been changed in the some_script.py file -> This is the crux of the question, where the import was identified as a function before adding the second import, it is now identified as a module. Ive added some lines to clarify what I meant when I said that I want to import and call the function -Has this made it any clearer, or do you want me to expand on something/include some more info?

Comment: In your code, you are trying to call load_settings instead of load_setting. Either this `def load_setting(setting):` is wrong or `a_dict = ls.load_settings('A')` is wrong.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 - load_settings -> typo in the question.

Comment: @kat Are you using a try except block in your code or something similar?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 None - How would exception handling effect the import?

Comment: @kat The only way I can reproduce your issue is by having a try statement around the functions load_settings and load_transforms. If not, I get a TypeError after 
`return MAPS[setting]`. Error is `TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable`. So I imagine you are doing something else with your MAPS import before it gets to that line?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 -No that's the entirety of that code, but your issue prompted me to go and look into the __init__ file -> and one of the module level imports there are:                   
from .load_settings import load_settings    
this must be overwriting either the module or the function name, which in turn causes the issue.

Comment: @kat Don't forget to add your solution if you found one and mark this as resolved.

Comment: Actually -this doesnt do anything about the issue -The change from function to module still occurs no matter of the innit import statement -> Ill add  the innit file as additional information to the ticket

Comment: @kat Can you show your whole init file? And are the other ones empty?

Comment: From settings\__init__.py:

`from .load_settings import load_settings
from .settings import MAPS
from .transforms import TRSFM
__all__ = ['load_settings', 'MAPS', 'TRSFM']`

from project\__init__.py:

`from .settings import *
from .scripts import *`

`from scripts\__init__.py:
from .some_script import *`

Comment: @kat Try commenting out the line in your scripts\__init__.py. It can cause unpredictable behavior it so could be the cause of this.

Comment: @kat last idea was from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393764/python-3-6-project-structure-leads-to-runtimewarning). Let us know here if you found a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mixture between relative imports in the **init**.py files and overlapping import names seems to have caused the issue -Once all imports were cleared out from the **init**.py files and relative imports changed to absolute the issue got resolved