# Import with calls out and from a folder

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I made the following architecture:

```py
parent/
      main.py
      tool/
        __init__.py
        base.py
        view.py
```

`base.py` and `view.py` hosts the classes of the same name.

```
__init__.py
from .base import Base
from .view import View
```

```
view.py
from .base import Base
```

```
main.py
from tool import View
```

- When I execute directly `main.py` its works fine.
- But when I execute only `view.py` with `python tool/view.py` I got the error:

```py
    from .base import Base
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

So if I change `from .base import Base` to `from base import Base` in `view.py`, `python tool/view.py` works but `python main.py` fails with:

```
    from base import Base
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
```

What import should be made to make both work?

`python main.py` and
`python tool/view.py`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first imports are fine, you should just change the second command to

```
python -m tool.view
```

Comment: Thanks @enzo ! It's works but also raise `RuntimeWarning: 'tool.view' found in sys.modules after import of package 'tool', but prior to execution of 'tool.view'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))` do you know what that means?

Comment: You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43393764/9997212) to some explanation. In your specific case, do you really need the imports in your *\_\_init\_\_.py*? If you don't, you can leave the file empty and the warning will go away.